# How to Get the value(label) from the TextField inside the custom cell of a table View to post on te URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, uitextview

I want my iOS app to pass to a URL the text the user types. The relevant code is pasted below. WHen I run the app, the text does not get assigned any value. It stays as null.

I am new to iOS programming and am probably missing something obvious here. Any help/pointers will be appreciated.

Mac OS version :  10.6.8 (64 bit)
Xcode version   :   3.2.3

In the snapshop.. "I have created a Table View and placed custom cell inside each row of a table. TextField is inside the custom cell view. Post is a button next to the textField which is a done Button. If I click that button, the text we are entering in the textField should post on URL which i have specified in my code snippet."

NOTE: The text is like a comment and posting this comment that should post on particular image in that cell.

I have copied the code snippet below. I have also attached an image to explain.

```
-(IBAction)postAction:(id)sender

{

    int index=[sender tag];

    homecell *cell = [[homecell alloc] init];

    UITextField *txt_c =(UITextField *)[cell.txt_comment viewWithTag:index];

    NSLog(@"jj %@",txt_c);

    gen_data *ut1=[[gen_data alloc]init];

    gen_data *ut=[gen_data getInstance];

}
```

Comment: Have you ever thought about upgrading your Xcode to the latest version first? 3.2.3 is ancient, I'm using 4.6.2

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have created that view using the interface builder, probably all you need is to connect that textfield as an **IBOutlet** and access the value.

**IBOutlet** is the key word here, search for it and you will find really fast the way to do it.

Check this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphone101/Articles/05_ConfiguringView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007514-CH7-SW15).

Answer (score 0):

You should get some basics of iOS programming first.

Why are you creating a totally new  custom cell that is irrelevant to your `UITableView`? When you create it that way, it's a totally new `UITableViewCell`.
You should connect it to it first, get its `NSIndexPath` and then operate with it and do what you want.

BTW, if you want to see the text of UITextfield you should `NSLog` `myTextField.text`

And you could easily write `viewWithTag:sender.tag`, no need to create an extra ivar here