# How to Get the value(label) from the TextField inside the custom cell of a table View to post on the URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, uitextfield

I want my iOS app to pass to a URL the text the user types. The relevant code is pasted below. When I run the app, the text does not get assigned any value. It stays as null.

I am new to iOS programming and am probably missing something obvious here. Any help/pointers will be appreciated.

Mac OS Version : 10.6.8 (64 bit) Xcode Version : 3.2.3

In the snapshop.. "I have created a Table View and placed custom cell inside each row of a table. TextField is inside the custom cell view. Post is a button next to the textField which is a done Button. If I click that button, the text we are entering in the textField should post on URL which i have specified in my code snippet."

NOTE: The text is like a comment and posting this comment that should post on particular image in that cell.

I have copied the code snippet below. I have also attached an image to explain.

```
-(IBAction)postAction:(id)sender

{

int index=[sender tag];

homecell *cell = [[homecell alloc] init];

UITextField *txt_c =(UITextField *)[cell.txt_comment viewWithTag:index];

NSLog(@"jj %@",txt_c);

gen_data *ut1=[[gen_data alloc]init];

gen_data *ut=[gen_data getInstance];

.... }
```

![In the snapshop.. "I have created a Table View and placed custom cell inside each row of a table. TextField is inside the custom cell view. Post is a button next to the textField which is a done Button. If I click that button, the text we are entering in the textField should post on URL which i have specified in my code snippet."![][1][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tnpQ.png)

Comment: Isn't this the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917321/how-to-get-the-valuelabel-from-the-textfield-inside-the-custom-cell-of-a-table?  Why are you asking again?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
NSLog(@"jj %@",txt_c);
```

Your `%@` is referring to the `UITextField` itself, and not the text (`NSString*`)

```
NSLog(@"jj %@",txt_c.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before appending user entered text first add percentage encoding like below

```
[@"" stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Also add the following

```
homecell *cell = [[homecell alloc] init];

UITextField *txt_c =(UITextField *)[cell.txt_comment viewWithTag:index];
```

if you are creating a new object of cell to fetch text user entered it will always be nil.
You have to fetch cell for the indexPath button was tapped and from that cell you can fetch the text.

Answer (score 0):

You are initialising a new cell when this method is called: `homecell *cell = [[homecell alloc] init];`. This creates a brand new cell and so obviously the text field will be empty.

You need to find some way of getting a handle on the cell which is in question.

There are several ways of doing this, for instance you could implement the UITextField delegate and do something with the text every time it changes, or you could hold a reference to the cell somewhere which corresponds to which cell it's in.

I can't tell you which way you should do it as I don't know which will work best for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom cell view then you can try this. Worked fine for me.

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
  static NSString *customCellView = @"CustomCellView";

  CustomCellView *cell = (CustomCellView *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:customCellView];
  if (cell == nil)
  {
      NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellView" owner:self options:nil];
      cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
  }

  cell.nameLabel.text = [_newArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  return cell;
  }

Comment: Hi, I have used this method. but i am getting error like expected error  before homecell..... this is my code,, i have changed simpleTableIdentifier to homecell...
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"homecell";
 
 homecell *cell = (homecell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:homecell];
 if (cell == nil) 
 {
  NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"homecell" owner:self options:nil];
  cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
 }

Comment: @Venkat Narahari Try this project and all your questions will be answered:-   https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bz5CZnhZ4WAvdXFLWjRRUjMyV2M/edit